# How To Speed Up Image Blur?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiimage, ios8, uiblureffect

I have the following code in my viewWillAppear in a modal uiviewcontroller.

I am including UIImage+ImageEffects.h to do the blurring of the background image in this example.

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:NO];

// grab an image of our parent view
UIView *parentView = self.presentingViewController.view;

UIImage *parentViewImage = [self takeSnapshotOfView:parentView];

UIImage *blurredImage = nil;

//BLUR THE IMAGE
blurredImage = [self blurWithImageEffects:parentViewImage];

// insert an image view with a picture of the parent view at the back of our view's subview stack...
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
imageView.image = blurredImage;
[self.view insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];

}
```

[EDIT] Adding Blur Methods

```
- (UIImage *)takeSnapshotOfView:(UIView *)view
{
    CGFloat reductionFactor = 1.5;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(view.frame.size.width/reductionFactor, view.frame.size.height/reductionFactor));
    [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width/reductionFactor, view.frame.size.height/reductionFactor) afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}

- (UIImage *)blurWithImageEffects:(UIImage *)image
{
    return [image applyBlurWithRadius:10 tintColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.2] saturationDeltaFactor:1.5 maskImage:nil];
}
```

The code works fine and the background shows up blurry but it is really noticeably slow on iPad 3 with iOS 8.  When the button to display this viewcontroller is tapped there is a pause before the viewcontroller slides up from the bottom.  If I remove the blur the view controller slides up faster.

I tried putting the code in the viewDidAppear but then there is a noticeable white background displayed for a few seconds before the blur appears.  But when in viewDidAppear the viewcontroller slides up immediately.

If I reduce the applyWithBlurRadius value this does not seem to reduce the time it takes to apply the blur.

Is there any way I can make it run faster?

Comment: You could try UIVisualEffect for iOS 8 devices.

Comment: @skorulls I would but I don't seem to have the same level of control using UIVisualEffects as there are only 3 levels of blur available that I cannot seem to change.  I have updated my question with the image blur method.

Answer (score 0):

GPUImage might solve your issue, Its fast and it doesn't put too much load on processing.

Link To Framework : https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

Link to use GPUImage Blur

- http://blog.bubbly.net/tag/gpu-image/
- http://www.raywenderlich.com/60968/ios-7-blur-effects-gpuimage

However a reference is shown below which will give you the basic idea:

First prepare your view which is to blurred:

```
- (NSData *)PhotoForBlurring:(UIView *)view{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, 1.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [data writeToFile:@"aName.png" atomically:YES];
    return data; }

-(void)sharingScrapPage{
     GPUImageiOSBlurFilter *blur = [[GPUImageiOSBlurFilter alloc]init];
     blur.blurRadiusInPixels=2.0;
     blur.downsampling=6.0;

     [blurview removeFromSuperview];
     blurview = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:getRectDisplay(0, 0, 480, 320)]; // Landscape Iphone 4S
     UIImage *imageForBlurring=[UIImage imageWithData:[self PhotoForBlurring:self.view]];
     NSData* pngdataForBlurring = UIImagePNGRepresentation (imageForBlurring);
     UIImage* blurImage = [UIImage imageWithData:pngdataForBlurring];
     blurImage=[blur imageByFilteringImage:blurImage];
     blurview.image=blurImage;
     [self.view addSubview:blurview];

     [progressHUD removeFromSuperview];
     progressHUD = [[ProgressHUD alloc]initWithFrame:getRectDisplay(190, 110, 100, 90)];
     [blurview addSubview:progressHUD]; }
```